# Probability for genetic combinations

Tags: probability, statistics

Thanks for your help!

We have 5 healthy children.  Recently, my wife become pregnant with #6.  A genetic screening revealed that she carries the gene for Cystic Fibrosis which by itself is meaningless, but if I carry the gene as well then the odds of conveying the illness to the child is 25%. I do not know if I carry the gene (but I do know that none of my 5 children have it).

What are the odds of having 5 healthy (non cystic fibrosis) kids if the odds of conveying the illness is 25% per child?

Taking this is step further, is there a way to 'combine' the entire scenario? The odds of my carrying the gene is 1 in 24, the odds of conveying the illness is 1 in 4 (25%) and on top of that I have 5 healthy children already.

I hope this makes sense!

Thanks again,
Ben

Comment: Why are "the odds of [you] carrying the gene" $1$ in $24$?

Comment: @Travis Maybe one out of every $24^2=576$ persons in the entire population has the phenotype (i.e. has the illness, cystic fibrosis)?

Comment: Statistically, the odds of someone of my ancestory having the gene is 1 in 24.  It is documented.

Comment: The probability is then $\frac{1}{24}\times\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{96}$, which is the probability you have the gene times the probability you both transmit it.

Comment: If you carried the gene, the probability that all $5$ kids would be healthy is $\left(\frac 34 \right)^5\sim .237$.  Not that low a chance.  I'll work the Bayesian calculation and post it below (if no one does it first).

Answer (score 3):

Trusting the data you provide, our prior is that you have a $\frac 1{24}\sim .0417$ chance of carrying the gene.  Now we have the additional information that none of the previous $5$ kids has the disease, which makes our new estimate for your probability $$p=\frac {(\frac 1{24})\times \left(\frac 34\right)^5}{(\frac 1{24})\times \left(\frac 34\right)^5+\frac {23}{24}\times 1}\sim .0102$$  So your probability is greatly reduced.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much.  So to clarify, the odds of my carrying the gene, based on the data I provided, is now .0102 or 1.02%.  The subsequent odds of conveying the illness to my children is 25% of that or .25% or 1 in 400. Correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct (based on the numbers you gave).